# MongoDB Fillter the records and Updating vs Updating with filters

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

If i want to update multiple documents based on multiple filter criteria which is the better approach?

1. Filter and get the documents (only _id field) which needs to be updated and supply the array of _id to updatemanyasync ($in) as a parameter and update . (see below 1)
2. Update the documents by supplying filter criteria directly.(see below 2)

---

Reason for this doubt. 
1. MongoDB search only for _id matches and update it. 
2. MongoDB search for the supplied mulitple criteria (multiple fields) each document and it will update.

What is the performance difference on these 2 approaches by spliting up the updates as 2 process 
Performance on Timeouts,Locks,Document Avalability after update.

Please help to share your suggestions and views.